# Magnitude of an edge in Python

Tags: python, math

I have 2 points in 3D with x, y, and z coordinates.
How do I calculate the magnitude of the edge that connects them?

Would this work?

```
abs( np.linalg.norm(p1) - np.linalg.norm(p2) )
```

where p1 and p2 are lists:

```
[x-coord, y-coord, z-coord]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you want the norm of the vector between the two points, i.e.

```
>>> p1 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> p2 = np.array([10, -3, 4])
>>> np.linalg.norm(p1-p2)
10.344080432788601
```

(They need to be arrays for elementwise subtraction to be this simple.)  Or, manually:

```
>>> sum((i-j)**2 for i,j in zip(p1, p2))**0.5
10.344080432788601
```

What `abs( np.linalg.norm(p1) - np.linalg.norm(p2) )` computes is more like the difference between the lengths of the vectors from `(0,0,0)` to `p1` and `(0,0,0)` to `p2` instead.